# Solving $\int \frac{1}{f(x) \sqrt{1-(f'(x))^2}} dx$

Tags: calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and assume that $f(x) \neq 0$ and $|f'(x) |<1$  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Does the indefinite

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{f(x) \sqrt{1-(f'(x))^2}} dx
\end{equation}

have a 'nice' expression in terms of $f(x)$? I expect not but perhaps I am overlooking something. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a no since you can find a function $f$ satisfying your properties such that $\tfrac1{f(x)\sqrt{1-(f^\prime(x))^2}}$ have no elementary antiderivative. The simplest example I can think of is the function $x\mapsto0.01\cos(x+\cos x)$, whose derivative is: $0.01(\sin x-1)(\sin(x+\cos x))$. You can verify that it does satisfy the conditions you mentioned.